# how can I set start_time and end_time when downloading a video with youtube_dl in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, youtube-dl

I wrote a very simple function to try out the youtube_dl module and it works fine but I can't seem to get it to work with `start_time` or `end_time` to download a specific part of a video.

Here is my code, it works but it always downloads the complete video instead of getting the requested chunk.

```py
def download_video(i, url, start_time, end_time):
    ydl_opts = {
        'format': 'bestaudio/best',
        'outtmpl': f'./media/{i}.%(ext)s',
        'start_time': start_time,
        'end_time': end_time,
        'postprocessors': [{
            'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio',
            'preferredcodec': 'mp3',
            'preferredquality': '192',
        }],
        'logger': TerminalLogger(),
        'progress_hooks': [download_finished_hook],
    }

    with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
        ydl.download([url])
```

Comment: anecdotally, it may depend on the requested format